# Canvas inline height and width attributes overridden with css styles. Is this is a bug?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, image-scaling

I recently [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770118/html5-canvas-image-scaling-to-a-smaller-size-and-back-to-original) on how to draw an image larger than my canvas onto the canvas without cropping and save the image back into its original dimensions after performing some changes on it. I found the solution is to set the inline `height` and `width` attributes for the canvas larger than the image, and use css `height` and `width` properties to style the canvas to fit into your layout.

For example, assuming my images could range between 400px to 2000 px in dimensions. But I don't want the canvas to be so big, and I don't want the images to be cropped as well (because when saving the image with `toDataURL` what is on the canvas is what is saved). This is what works:

```
//style
#mycanvas{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

<canvas id="mycanvas" width="2000" height="2000" />
```

This works fine and my images come out well.
But is this behavior buggy and bound to be changed/fixed in the future? I'm planning to use this solution for a task at hand.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behaviour is commonly used for controlling the size of a canvas:

- Attributes for resolution
- CSS for stretching/shrinking

See [Canvas width and height in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938346/canvas-width-and-height-in-html5).

Comment: Aha... I think its safe to use it for live purposes! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*I know its been a long time since the question was asked, but I have another solution that can be used as well.*

You can try using the  [canvasContext.drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) function, to resize the image as you draw the image into your canvas.

Syntax: `void ctx.drawImage(image, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);`

- dx and dy are the destination canvas' x and y coordinates
- dWidth and dHeight are the dimensions in which your image will be drawn on the canvas.

(*If you know the size of the canvas and your image, you can calculate what these values need to be*)