# How to change the style size of a canvas dynamically by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

The size (width and height) of a canvas can be changed, but the style size of the canvas can not be changed dynamically.

```
canvas = document.getElementById('test_fabric');
ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.style.width = 1000;  // does not work.
canvas.style.height = 260;  // does not work.
canvas.width = 100;  // works.
canvas.height = 100;  // works.
```

Both canvas.width and canvas.height work well, but both canvas.style.width and canvas.style.height do not work.

In my case, the style size of the canvas only can be changed by a css file or inline style of the canvas.

```
canvas#test_fabric {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background:gold;
}
```

or

```
<div><canvas id="test_fabric" width="200" height="200" 
style="width:200px; height:200px"></canvas></div>
```

Note: The css file becomes ineffective when the inline style exists.

What's the way to change the style size of a canvas dynamically by JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry, I meant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779429/canvas-inline-height-and-width-attributes-overridden-with-css-styles-is-this-is

Comment: Have you tried specifying CSS length units, eg., "px"? `canvas.style.width = "1000px"`

Comment: I try to use "canvas.setAttribute('width', '500');"
and "canvas.setAttribute('height', '500');", they do not work when defining canvas tag without style, and when defining canvas tag with style, Chrome reports a message:  
"[Report Only] Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-8qEYHk4WwsvJKgLquQfLnw2DRoaMh4sWGNj24adrRLQ='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."

Comment: So...you've ignored my suggestion, and ignored  the answer below that says the same thing, and instead you're now commenting about some *other* thing that didn't work?

Comment: canvas.style.width and canvas.style.height worked when specifying CSS length units "px". nnnnnn: thank you!

Answer (score 10):

The style properties' width and height requires the measurement for its values while html attributes' width and height does not require. So, you need to set `px, em or %` etc. explicitly in your code:

```
canvas = document.getElementById('test_fabric');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.style.width = '1000px'; // explicitly setting its unit 'px'
canvas.style.height = '260px';
```

style.width/height without unit is invalid rule for css.

Comment: Thank your answer! Bhojendra Nepal.

Comment: @Calvin You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

I have used jQuery that uses the `css` method for height and width setting:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test_fabric").css({
      "border-color": "#C1E0FF",
      "border-width": "1px",
      "border-style": "solid",
      "height": "500px",
      "width": "500px"
    });
  });
</script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div><canvas id="test_fabric" width="200" height="200"></canvas></div>
</div>
```

Comment: abhay vyas: I tried to use jquery as your way and found it worked. Thank you!

Comment: If you use fabric.js, I found you can do this by:     canvas.setDimensions({width:800, height:200},{backstoreOnly:true});    canvas.setDimensions({width:'800px', height:'200px'},{cssOnly:true});

Comment: setting the `width` and `height` as css` will only stretch the canvas image. that canvas should still be a 200x200 px area stretched to 500x500 px